# Можно ли аналогично захвату контекста с помощью лямбды захватить необходимые данные с помощью обычной функции, но сохраняя необходимую сигнатуру

Tags: c++, функции, функциональное-программирование, анонимная-функция

Можно ли аналогично захвату контекста с помощью лямбды захватить необходимые данные с помощью обычной функции, но сохраняя необходимую сигнатуру? К примеру, у меня есть функция, со следующей сигнатурой `void func(functional(void(int)));`с помощью лямбды я могу дополнить эту функцию объектами из контекста, в котором находится лямбда, к примеру

```
int a = 10;
func([&](int b, int c){
  std::cout << a + b + c;
})
```

Могу ли я сделать примерно тоже самое, но использовав обычную функцию, не используя лямбду?. Я понимаю, что есть вариант присвоить лямбду к указателю на функцию и использовать, но в данном случае это не подходит. У меня есть подозрение, что в данном случае поможет bind, но я не очень понимаю как его использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лямбда функция это функциональный класс с оператором вызова `operator()`. Этот класс может содержать в себе указатели на источник вызова (адрес стека например) и может использовать все локальные переменные.

Обычной функции никакой дополнительной информации не передаётся и по-этому она не может использовать переменные, что ниже по стеку.

Класс функций `std::function` покрывает все лямбда-функции и все статические. Это универсальный класс, с каждым типом функций работает индивидуально.

Comment: вообще то они не функцию создают,  а функтор, то есть класс с `operator()`

Comment: я смотрю компиляцию в ассемблере и не вижу там никаких объявлений классов и переменных `this`. покомпилируйте сами. @KoVadim

Comment: А почему, в таком случае, передаваемая функция подходит по сигнатуре?

Comment: логично, что  в ассембленом коде нет никаких классов и переменных. Да, компилятор может многое, но правила есть правила. Вот пример https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGlvc3RyZWFtPgojaW5jbHVkZSA8ZnVuY3Rpb25hbD4KCnZvaWQgZnVuYyhzdGQ6OmZ1bmN0aW9uPHZvaWQoaW50LGludCk+IGYpCnsKCn0KCmludCBtYWluKCkKewppbnQgYSA9IDEwOwpmdW5jKFsmXShpbnQgYiwgaW50IGMpewogIHN0ZDo6Y291dCA8PCBhICsgYiArIGM7Cn0pOwp9&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0

Comment: В вашем примере всё сделано стандартно, а когда я добавил опцию `-Os`, то все деструкторы исчезли. осталась только эта функция сложения `*AX+*DX+*SI` причём по ссылкам. https://godbolt.org/z/cz5q7x @KoVadim

Comment: компилятор имеет право делать любые оптимизации, пока не нарушается видимое поведение программы - `as if`.

Comment: класс `function` это очень широкое поле, принимает много функций. Внутри этого класса уже храняться аргументы по ссылке. Но если создаёте объект `function` в области, где нет переменной `a`, то будет ошибка компиляции. @Denver Toha

Comment: @AlexGlebe вижу поправили ответ (хотя и кривовато), разобрались с тем, что такое лямбда?

Comment: Я с лямбда давно знаком, но с объектом `functional` не успел всё разжевать, как лайк поставили. Скоро всё поправлю. @KoVadim

Comment: перечитал несколько раз, но первый абзац так и не поправлен, (или нужно добавить ссылку на доказательство данного утверждения). А дальше как то сумбурно-сумбурно написано.

Answer (score 2):

Функция определяется в глобальной области, а не в локальной, и все, что она может "захватить" -глобальную переменную.

Так что у вас это может выглядеть разве что так:

```
int global_a_for_func;
void func(int b, int c) {
    std::cout << global_a_for_func + b + c;
}

....
int main() {
    int a = 10;
    
    global_a_for_func = a; func(10,15);
```